# Gui Design with HTML

Tags: jquery, html, autoit, windows-scripting

Is there any way to design AutoIt script GUI using HTML? Or any web resources? Just a random question in mind that I hope will merit favorable answers from the most prestigious members of stackoverflow.

If yes, is there a way to run javascript in it? and potentially animate it with Jquery?

If the above is no or can not be answered, is there a way to animate AutoIt GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To design an AutoIt GUI with html, no there are no tools at the moment.

However, you can embed an Internet Explorer activeX object into a GUI, and load the html into that. For an example see [_IECreateEmbedded](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IECreateEmbedded.htm). That can be animated with javascript and jquery in the same way as any other web page.

If it is just animating GUI elements you are interested in, then doing it natively will be a lot more resource friendly. Depending on what animation you want to do, it can be as simple as just setting the control position in a loop, using one of the WinAPI functions like [AnimateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or doing the graphics yourself using GDI+. There are plenty of examples of all three on the [AutoIt Forums](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/).

Comment: But I do have one last question.
Lets say I used the first method you mentioned. (IE)
for example, if I load menu.html which will be located online. Will autoit be able to detect the clicks made and trigger a function locally?
lets say I click button A, can it run function A?

Comment: @user2128576, Yes, it took a bit of playing around and reading MSDN, but I put together [an example](http://pastebin.com/G57rjp8M).

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I was looking for!
Thanks you so much for this.

I'd was really hoping it was possible, since putting content on web is easier to update! thanks so much! :D
you saved me time.

Comment: @user2128576, but remember it won't work for people who aren't connected, and it does use up more resources.

Comment: You can always create a local server and access it through your iexplorer control, this way you can have the html files together with your project. PD AnimateWindow function will only make your entire window appear or disappear.